# Blue Bar below picture clickable link

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with a Blue Bar about 10 pixels in height appearing on a clickable image. It has a transparent background and when you hove over the image that is linked a blue bar appears. I have tried to use `border: none;` with no luck does anyone have any tips I have included a picture with the blue bar I am talking about I had to blur the logo but you get the point.[image]

example here http://jsfiddle.net/wdY26/

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle of this or a link at least?

Comment: ill create a fiddle link

Comment: hover over top of the images of the cats and it appears at the very bottom of the image It does it in Safari and Chrome for me I havent tried another browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#369; /* <= Your problem */
    text-decoration:none;
}
```